# Sort array of arrays by hash key in value and reinsert key

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'd like to reorder an array of arrays. By default, the array is sorted by the English keys:

```
english_sorted_terms = [
  [
    "A1_english", {"domains"=>[], "en"=>{"name"=>"A_english", "def"=>"A"}, "de"=>{"name"=>"Z_german", "def"=>"..." }} 
  ],
  [
    "Z1_english", {"domains"=>[], "en"=>{"name"=>"Z_english", "def"=>"Z"}, "de"=>{"name"=>"A_german", "def"=>"..."}}
  ]
]
```

After sorting, 'Z1_english' should be the first element because it contains the name 'A_german'.

My other attempts do correct the 'de' sub-key but I cannot reinsert the right parent key or the key but the sorting isn't right

```
english_sorted_terms
  .map { |term| term[1] } 
  .sort_by { |key| key["de"]['name'] }
```

```
english_sorted_terms
  .map { |term| [term[1]].sort_by! { |key| key["de"]['name'] }.unshift term[0] }
```

`.sort_by! { |key| key["de"]['name'] }` is working but it removes the first array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby sorting works by comparing elements and you can define the comparison criteria yourself. In this example you compare with original array item's second element's ['de']['name']. For example:

```
english_sorted_terms.sort { |a, b| a.second['de']['name'] <=> b.second['de']['name'] }
```

See https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sort.

Comment: Your code example should use `a[1]` and `b[1]` instead of `.second`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Great! Sometimes, things can be so easy - thanks for your help!

Comment: You are right. `second` is a Rails addition and not part of ruby.